# In Ruby, can I access module methods without using the module name?

Tags: ruby, methods, module, visibility

I have the following Ruby code:

```
gallery = ViewableGallery.new(gallery_config.title, gallery_config.description, gallery_config.slug, \
  gallery_config.sources, gallery_config.upload_date, gallery_config.map_url, gallery_config.map_title, \
  gallery_config.year, viewable_photos).
  update_using( \
    GalleryGenerator.add_tabs_before_every_description_line(2), \
    GalleryGenerator.add_links_to_descriptions, \
    GalleryGenerator.for_each_photo(&GalleryGenerator.add_tabs_before_every_description_line(3)), \
    GalleryGenerator.for_each_photo(&GalleryGenerator.add_links_to_descriptions), \
    GalleryGenerator.for_each_photo(&GalleryGenerator.remove_final_empty_line_from_description))
```

**As you can see, GalleryGenerator is repeated many times. Can I drop that somehow?**  Using this does not help:

```
include GalleryGenerator
```

For reference, the module itself:

```
module GalleryGenerator
  def self.add_tabs_before_every_description_line(how_many_tabs)
    lambda do |mutable_viewable_content|
      mutable_viewable_content.description = add_tabs_before_every_line(mutable_viewable_content.description, how_many_tabs)
      return mutable_viewable_content
    end
  end

# ...

  def self.for_each_photo(&update_function)
    return lambda do |mutable_viewable_gallery|
      mutable_viewable_gallery.photos.each do |mutable_viewable_photo|
        update_function.call(mutable_viewable_photo)
      end
      return mutable_viewable_gallery
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just include the module and make the method instance methods not class ones:

```
module GalleryGenerator
  def add_tabs_before_every_description_line(how_many_tabs)
    lambda do |mutable_viewable_content|
      mutable_viewable_content.description = add_tabs_before_every_line(mutable_viewable_content.description, how_many_tabs)
      return mutable_viewable_content
    end
  end

# ...

  def for_each_photo(&update_function)
    return lambda do |mutable_viewable_gallery|
      mutable_viewable_gallery.photos.each do |mutable_viewable_photo|
        update_function.call(mutable_viewable_photo)
      end
      return mutable_viewable_gallery
    end
  end
end
```